# how to insert an image file into existing ms word file using command prompt?

Tags: cmd, robotframework

I am working on Robot Framework. I want to create a report of a test case execution.
I have been trying to insert an image into existing ms word file via command prompt using 'Run' command in Robot framework.
is there any command like echo or edit which does the job?

Comment: The output of RF is an XML file. Why don't you write a tool to create a world file from that?

Comment: i was looking for a easy solution, if someone could suggest some commands somewhere(in CMD,or RF itself)... by the way, i am going to try "execute javascript" in RF, seems it will work fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Win32::OLE module in Perl to do this. There is an example [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/perl/word.html).

Or maybe some VBScript with OLE, like [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_automation_word.php#SaveAsPDF).

Comment: Have look here then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659018/accessing-microsoft-automation-objects-from-python

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I think i will use "EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT" command in RF to solve this. I will have to start a browser every time however. Hope this works as JS has functionality to edit word files.