# Pypyodbc: return field description of specific field in specific MS Access table?

Tags: python-3.x, pypyodbc

I'm trying to retrieve description (or other property) of field in MS Access database.

Something like in recordset of VBA:

```
For Each Field In Recordset.Fields
    Debug.Print "Name: " & Field.Name
    Debug.Print "Type: " & Field.Type
    Debug.Print "Size: " & Field.ActualSize
    Debug.Print "Value: " & Field.Value
Next
```

Is there any way how to do this with pypyodbc (or other ODBC module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cursor.description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes) attribute will give you the following information about each column in the cursor:

name
type_code
display_size
internal_size
precision
scale
null_ok

For any other information on the fields in an Access table you will need to use COM to create an Access DAO object and then pull the information from the `Fields` collection of the table's `TableDef` object. See

[Accessing Microsoft Automation Objects from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659018/2144390)

for more information on using COM from Python on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, I was already using this. However I need more detailed information on columns and tables.

Using COM seems great, as I can use my VBA knowledge there.

However for quick fix I have swaped pypyodbc to pyodbc, which have lot more options on columns and tables.